# Python Polars to Pandas conversion changes python objects to bytes datatype

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I can create a Polars dataframe (df) such that it holds a column with a user-defined Python object.
When I convert this df to Pandas (using .to_pandas() method), the Python objects are converted into bytes data type and I'm not able to get the original object.

How can I get the original object after it has been converted to bytes? Or is there a way to prevent this conversion?

Here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

df = pl.DataFrame({"my_class": [MyClass(1,2), MyClass(3,4)]})
print(df.to_pandas())
```

[polars df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Nv0.png)

[df.to_pandas()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVtt8.png)

Comment: Good question. It looks like `.to_pandas()` goes through arrow e.g. compare `df.to_arrow()` to `df.to_numpy()`

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/23c367b59f410af5ec4e0a31ba749995366f6cb2/py-polars/src/dataframe.rs#L838 seems to be where this happens. I think you may need to ask on Github/Discord as it looks like this requires some "internals knowledge" to answer. Perhaps something needs to be added to support "roundtripping" opaque Objects.

Comment: This has come up on the bug tracker https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13021